# How can I change the color of a single edge in a matplotlib bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a bar plot and I would like to change the color of the edges of each bar separately. For instance, the top edge black while the other edges are white. The `edgecolor` argument sets the color of all edges of the bar, but I haven't found any information on how to set the color of each edge independently.

Comment: The only thing you can do is draw an extra line for that edge.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that. What you can do is to make a single bar frame a different color. The only other thing I can do is to use axhline to draw a line at the top of each bar.